# Handle AntiForgery Token in Winform and WebAPI

Tags: winforms, asp.net-web-api, antiforgerytoken

What's the best way to deal with Antiforgery on methods with `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute` attribute while calling from a non-browser client, say `WinForm`?

Based on what I know, below is how anti forgery works:

1. A hidden input field is added to the page, e.g.
2. A cookie with the same name is also sent to the client
3. On the next request, both the cookie and the hidden input field is sent to server. Server calls `AntiForgery.Validate(token, cookie)` to confirm that the request is legit.

All works fine in a web app. It doesn't seem to work in WinForm. Here is what I do:

1. Using `HttpClient`, I do a get to a page containing the token.
2. I parse the page and grab the hidden input field. I also pick up the cookie.
3. I pass the cookie as is. On top of that, I add a new header `__RequestVerificationToken` with value from the hidden field.
4. I step into the server code.
5. The `AntiForgery.Validate(xx,yy)` fails with error: 
   **The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user X, but the current user is Y.**

Comment: At what point are you authenticating during this sequence? (if at all). This error tends to occur when you retrieve a token before authentication and then send the token back, this time to an authenticated session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. It needs Forms Authentication to be done prior and pass the cookies in subsequent WebAPI calls. So here's the revised flow:

1) Load the login form using HttpWebRequest (GET)

2) Do a POST on the login form using credentials. Do supply a **cookiecontainer** in HttpWebRequest

3) The cookiecontainer now contains the Auth cookies and  **__RequestVerificationToken**

4) Grab the __RequestVerificationToken from any subsequent GET or even from the output from login result

5) For the WebAPI Post call, pass the cookiecontainer as is. Also include a **header** __RequestVerificationToken with value from prev step.