# Provide AntiForgery Token with System.Net.Http.HttpClient and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms, asp.net-mvc-4, winforms-to-web

I have a WPF (could be any winform I guess) app that tries to login to a standard MVC 5 website using a **HttpClient**.

> Normally I can login successfully with a call to **PostAsync()** where I provide the UserName and Password params in a **HttpContent**!

However, when I add the **[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]** to my controller's Login (POST) action, the PostAsync() call fails with Internal Server Error.

I have tried collecting the "__RequestVerificationToken" from a simple GET request and sending it with my POST request by adding it to the POST params, the Header of the request or the HttpHandler's **CookieContainer** (or any combination of the three) but still I get error 500 from the server.

I know it can be done with HttpWebRequests ([apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467804/handle-antiforgery-token-in-winform-and-webapi)) but I don't know what I'm missing when using a HttpClient. I also don't know what exactly went wrong on the server side.. or how to check that since the code never reaches my controller method.

Did someone else try this by any chance?

**EDIT 1**:

I'm adding the raw data sent by the **browser** for both GET and POST:

```
GET http://localhost:57457/Account/Login HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: http://localhost:57457/Account/Login
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
DNT: 1
Host: localhost:57457
Cookie: NavigationTreeViewState=%5b%7b%27N0_1%27%3a%27T%27%2c%27N0%27%3a%27T%27%7d%2c%27N0_1_2%27%2c%7b%7d%5d; style=default; __RequestVerificationToken=Bak42Ga5sHJitYlmut6OgvmqXNmP7kKQRNaMSsLMAUh86iHGGmz5pnNfz_soKu46Wax9sG23arPOTnSh1bvaWyWqQ9NH4GJxFmendW8VFTg1

RESPONSE:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcRUJTLkNvZGVcUHJvamVjdHNcQ1ZSUE9TX1dlYlNpdGVcQ1ZSUE9TX1dlYlNpdGVcQWNjb3VudFxMb2dpbg==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 04 Dec 2014 10:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 1734
[View page content]
```

---

```
POST http://localhost:57457/Account/Login HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: http://localhost:57457/Account/Login
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 180
DNT: 1
Host: localhost:57457
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: NavigationTreeViewState=%5b%7b%27N0_1%27%3a%27T%27%2c%27N0%27%3a%27T%27%7d%2c%27N0_1_2%27%2c%7b%7d%5d; style=default; __RequestVerificationToken=Bak42Ga5sHJitYlmut6OgvmqXNmP7kKQRNaMSsLMAUh86iHGGmz5pnNfz_soKu46Wax9sG23arPOTnSh1bvaWyWqQ9NH4GJxFmendW8VFTg1

__RequestVerificationToken=Bak42Ga5sHJitYlmut6OgvmqXNmP7kKQRNaMSsLMAUh86iHGGmz5pnNfz_soKu46Wax9sG23arPOTnSh1bvaWyWqQ9NH4GJxFmendW8VFTg1&UserName=test&Password=test

RESPONSE:
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad request (user/password for testing purposes only)
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcRUJTLkNvZGVcUHJvamVjdHNcQ1ZSUE9TX1dlYlNpdGVcQ1ZSUE9TX1dlYlNpdGVcQWNjb3VudFxMb2dpbg==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 04 Dec 2014 10:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 4434
[View page content]
```

**EDIT 2**:

This is what my app sends for GET and POST:

```
GET http://localhost:57457/Account/Login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:57457
Connection: Keep-Alive

POST http://localhost:57457/Account/Login HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost:57457
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=df9nBSP_J1IiLrv84RwrkmvbYBrnH4iqv97wRvz6HMPLWBhgI4XzGeAFcschovHwD8mTtHU6xrmVxz1Ku96_BaoB79le_vLTcrgGemU4gjc1
Content-Length: 163
Expect: 100-continue

__RequestVerificationToken=df9nBSP_J1IiLrv84RwrkmvbYBrnH4iqv97wRvz6HMPLWBhgI4XzGeAFcschovHwD8mTtHU6xrmVxz1Ku96_BaoB79le_vLTcrgGemU4gjc1&UserName=test&Password=test
```

And finally this is the error:

**[HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005): Validation of the provided anti-forgery token failed. The cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" and the form field "__RequestVerificationToken" were swapped.]**

Thanks!

Comment: Could you also post the RAW http responses

Comment: Just the headers btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You d probably need to include aspnet session id cookie with your requests

EDIT: 
OK ur right, it is not the session id, but you need two token to send back to your post action.

I think what you re doing wrong is using same value for both tokens, but they should be different, altho name of both tokens is __RequestVerificationToken.
Token grabbed from cookie should be send back as cookie and token grabbed from form field goes back as form field.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's the case. It really doesn't make any sense to do that and besides, I don't pass any session id when I login without the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] and it works just fine.

Comment: As far as I know the generated forgery token is bound to a session value which for security reasons stays on server, so requesting the token, and validating afterwards, as during login, should happen in the same session.

Comment: As far as the server is concerned, everything IS happening in the same session. That being said, I definitively doubt the fact that the session has anything to do with this (you can see from my edit what data/cookies the browser is using)

Comment: Yes, that was it! There are two token values and I foolishly sent the cookie value only for both. Now that error does make a lot of sense :). Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're missing the anti-forgery token from `HtmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken()` in your POST from your application.

You'll need to load a page from your WPF application with `HtmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken()` on the view. Then take the value of the hidden input element with the name `__RequestVerificationToken` and attach it to your login POST request to the server.

Comment: Sorry, I have left out that info from my question, but I tried that too: I made a GET request, fished out the __RequestVerificationToken and added it to all the places I could think of: the post params (to simulate that hidden browser field), the request header (because I saw the browser does that too) and the cookie (because my first GET request placed it there anyway). Sadly none of them in any combination did not work.

Comment: @raptor Have you tried using something like Fiddler to inspect a real login request then see what your app is submitting?

Comment: I am very sorry but I don't know how to use fiddler to monitor the app. It doesn't show any traffic when I login using the app. For now I added to the question the data I get from my browser, I will look into how (or if) I can actually monitor the app with fiddler and come back with my findings.

Comment: I managed to work the fiddler after many painful attempts (the documentation available for IIS interaction is mostly misleading). I added the results to my question. One good thing is that I got to see the actual error. Maybe now I can figure out what it means :)

Answer (score 1):

I just had to do figure this out myself. Below is the code that I wrote that works. You'll need to modify some variables that make sense for your application including the web client's `.BaseAddress`, the path to your login page, and the shape of the model that you `POST` to successfully log in.

```cs
#nullable enable

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace **FIXME**;

public class WebClient
{
    private readonly CookieContainer _cookieContainer;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly string _loginPath;

    public WebClient(Uri baseAddress, string loginPath)
    {
        _cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        _client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = _cookieContainer }) { BaseAddress = baseAddress };
        _loginPath = loginPath;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetAntiforgeryToken()
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync(_loginPath);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var match = Regex.Match(content, "name=\"__RequestVerificationToken\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"(.*?)\"");

        return match.Success ? match.Groups[1].Value : throw new Exception("Unable to get anti-forgery token");
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> LogIn(string username, string password, string antiforgeryToken)
    {
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("__RequestVerificationToken", antiforgeryToken);

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent
        (
            new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Username", username },
                { "Password", password },
                { "__RequestVerificationToken", antiforgeryToken }
            }
        );

        return await _client.PostAsync(_loginPath, content);
    }

    public CookieContainer CookieContainer => _cookieContainer;

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> NavigateTo(string uri)
    {
        return await _client.GetAsync(uri);
    }

    public Cookie? GetCookie(string cookieName)
    {
        return _cookieContainer.GetCookies(_client.BaseAddress).Cast<Cookie>().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == cookieName);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var baseAddress = new Uri("**FIXME**");
var loginPath = "**FIXME**"; 
var username = "**FIXME**";
var password = "**FIXME**";

var webClient = new WebClient(baseAddress, loginPath);
var antiforgeryToken = await webClient.GetAntiforgeryToken();
var loginResponse = await webClient.LogIn(username, password, antiforgeryToken);
```